# Why does this code not remove Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I spent some time trying to remove layout (defined in _ViewStart) using:

```
@Layout = ""
```

and

```
@Layout = null
```

Why does it only work using block?

```
@{
  Layout = "";
}
```

In my vision, both ways should work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`@Layout` is a code nugget.
It prints the value of the `Layout` property.

The Razor parser stops at the space after the word `Layout`, so the `= null` is parsed as literal markup.

You want to execute a statement, not print a value, so you need to use a code *block* (`@{ ... }`).

For more information, see [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-4-anatomy-of.html).